# Computation of stable cohomology ring of SL_n(Z) using algebraic topology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

It is known that $H^k(SL(n,\mathbb{Z}))$ is independent of $n$ for $n \gg k$, so we can define a stable cohomology ring 
$$V = \text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} H^{\ast}(SL(n,\mathbb{Z});\mathbb{R}).$$
  Using analytic tools, Borel proved that $V$ is an exterior algebra generated in degrees $3, 5, 7, \ldots$.  Is there  proof of this using more traditional algebraic topology tools?

Comment: Short answer: no. Such a new proof would be a notable event and you would have noticed the echo of it.
